# Could Android Emulator access file in PC hard drive?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to write a simple app that displays an image in Android Studio using NDK, JNI.

My question is: Could Android Emulator access my image, which is located in my PC Hard Drive (D:/Pictures/myImage.jpg in this case). Or do I have to copy and paste the image to the Emulator's internal storage? If both of them are possible then which one is easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to put a picture into your app would be to set it up as a resource. If you want to load an image dynamically (ie. for testing or something) then you would have to put it to the phone's storage.

As far as I'm aware, the emulator can't browse the computer's files.

Comment: So I need to copy and paste it to the folder /app/res right? If so, how can I hard code the path? Assume that I use fopen in C++ to load it. Is fopen("app/res/myImage.jpg") correct or I have to paste in the full path?